# Cross Compile nghttp2 for Windows on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, cross-compiling, nghttp2

I am looking for the steps how to cross-compile the nghttp2 library on Ubuntu for Windows machines. On the internet I can't find any good documentation on this topic.

Could anyone help me out?

I already tried steps such as using `cross-compile-prefix` which unfortunately is not known by nghttp2

I need to build nghttp2 both for Win32 and Win64 target machines to use in a Curl build later (I have found the documentation to do so, however nghttp2 is still missing...)

Comment: @Optimus1 what error do you get? I have compiled it for Windows as well, but it's been a while..